# Angular2 calling method of component from template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am too deep in Angular2 now. But stuck at one place. Below is my template code:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let group of groupList">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <some-child-component [store]="group[0]" [class.hide]="evalStore(group[0])"></some-child-component>
                    </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

I am calling `evalStore(group[0])` method from my template. This method is present in the respective component class, as shown below:

```
evalStore(item:any) {
    console.log('inside evalStore');
     if(item === undefined){
       return false;
     } else {
       return  item.type !== 'store';
     }
  }
```

Due to some reason, this method is not getting called. My chrome dev tool's console window is not showing any error relevant to it.

Please help...

Comment: Angular is not throwing errors correctlt sometimes. In Chrome, try ticking the checkbox "Pause on Caught Exceptions". It might help you find the source of the error

Answer (score 0):

You're using the value binding incorrectly. `[class.hide]` is not a valid attribute. Square brackets are used to bind an attribute to a value or expression. Like you have here.

```
<div [store]="group[0]">
```

You're trying to do a class binding which requires a value binding to [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass) and then an expression containing an object of key/value pairs. Each key represents the class name, each value represents an expression that should return a boolean `true` or `false`. This works for multiple classes.

```
<div [ngClass]="{hide: evalStore(group[0])}">
```

If your class name uses special characters like dashes `-` you'll need to wrap your key in quotes.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hide-me': evalStore(group[0])}">
```